# Populating settings variables via SQLite database entries

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am wondering how to accomplish something. I have a database with the following structure and data:

```
    database.execSQL("create table records (" 
            + "_id integer primary key autoincrement," 
            + "name varchar not null," 
            + "calories integer not null," 
            + "protein integer not null," 
            + "carbs integer not null," 
            + "fat integer not null," 
            + "date integer not null" 
            + ")");

    database.execSQL("create table settings (" 
            + "_id integer primary key autoincrement," 
            + "field varchar not null," 
            + "value varchar not null" 
            + ")");

    database.execSQL("insert into settings (field, value) VALUES ('target_calories', '2700')");
    database.execSQL("insert into settings (field, value) VALUES ('target_protein', '200')");
    database.execSQL("insert into settings (field, value) VALUES ('target_carbs', '300')");
    database.execSQL("insert into settings (field, value) VALUES ('target_fat', '80')");
```

Now, what I want to do in another activity is grab all of the values from the settings table so I can compare them to what a user enters into the records table for today.

So basically, I'm trying to figure out the best way to grab the settings and dump them into variables, i.e.:

```
int target_calories = Integer.parseInt("2700");
int target_protein = Integer.parseInt("200");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to query the database, or to parse an Integer?

Comment: I want to dump the settings into variables for use in an activity.

Comment: i think hashmap is what i'm looking for ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to write a SQL Query to get out these values from your database table and write them to your variables or a Map as you said in your comment.

```
 Cursor cursor = database.query("settings", new String[] { "field", "value" },null, null, null, null,null);
 Map<String,Integer> settings = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
     settings.put(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getInt(1));
 }
```

**Note:** Keep in mind to close cursor after use.

For better performance, I would recommend to make your field as Integer and then use SparseIntArray instead of HashMap for [Performance Benefits](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html)

Hope this helps.